# Does NPM run scripts called dependencies when running npm i?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is `npm i` supposed to run run scripts called `dependencies` when `npm i` is run?

It does in my case in the lastest version of node (v19.8.1) and I'm wondering if this is a bug?

To reproduce try this:

```
mkdir test
cd test
npm init -y
```

And just make the `package.json` look like this:

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dependencies": "cd app",
    "echo": "echo \"$PWD\""
  },  
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "node-pretty-log": "*"
  }
}
```

And try running `npm i`.  The following should be the output:

```
npm i
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/oleersoy/Temp/temp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cd app
npm ERR! sh: line 0: cd: app: No such file or directory

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/oleersoy/.npm/_logs/2023-04-17T18_50_22_257Z-debug-0.log
oleersoy@Oles-MacBook-Pro temp % npm i
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/oleersoy/Temp/temp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cd app
npm ERR! sh: line 0: cd: app: No such file or directory
```

We can see that it tried to `cd app`, and since the directory `app` does not exist the error was created when it tried to run the `dependencies` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dependencies` script is run after modifying `node_modules` *if* there were any changes - [see the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts).

Comment: Ah - Good to know - It was a bit of a surprise :)